# Excel/Pentaho double group by + count

Tags: sql, excel, statistics, analytics, pentaho

I am having some problems dealing with Excel and pentaho (I guess due to my 0 experience with these tools...).
Having the following data set:

```
  Interaction date  interaction_name
    21/08/13    course view
    21/08/13    course view
    21/08/13    forum view forum
    21/08/13    course view
    21/08/13    course view
    21/08/13    course view
    22/08/13    forum view forum
    22/08/13    course view
    22/08/13    forum view forum
    22/08/13    user view all
    22/08/13    user view
    22/08/13    blog view
    22/08/13    user view all
```

I would like to represent that on the 21/08/2013 there has been 4 course views and 1 forum view, on 22/08/2013 2 forum views, 1 course view, 3 user view all... and so on.

That is (from the SQL perspective) kind of a count in a double group by. First group by date, then group by interaction and count them. The correct SQL query could also help me.

I just cant figure out how to make it. I tried with excel and with pentaho, but seems that I am missing something...

Any help would be really apreciated! Thanks

My report in pentaho so far: Already tried with aggregation count, but it counts every interaction, without making any difference among them.
[image]

Comment: Where is the original data? In an Excel sheet? Have you succeeded in reading it into Pentaho? Could cou include a screenshot of your Pentaho transformation so far?

Comment: No programming involved here. This question should go to a different website. E.g. the Pentaho forums, since its about using Pentaho software?

Comment: I have seen many questions about analytics in this forum, that is why I decided to post it here. And the question is not about pentaho software itself, but about analytics.

@MarcusRickert yes, the original data is in an excel sheet, I added a screenshot of my current report status. Thanks

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I (most likely) don't second your opinion. Writing Pentaho jobs and transformations is very close to writing programs and among the SE sites SO is probably the best choice. Even setting up complex configurations at application level generate good questions for SO. Based on the information available in the question I cannot decide yet whether "coding" or a complex configuration is required or simple configuration at application level would suffice. In the latter case the question becomes a little less suitable for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marcus Rickert asked, you didn't specified data source, but I will suppose that is some SQL like database because you asked for right SQL query.

This one:

```
SELECT Interaction_date, Interaction_name, count(Interaction_name) from your_table group by Interaction_date,Interaction_name order by Interaction_date asc;
```

It will produce:

```
Interaction_date    Interaction_name    count
---------------------------------------------
21/08/13            course view         5
21/08/13            forum view forum    1
22/08/13            forum view forum    2
22/08/13            course view         1
22/08/13            user view all       2
22/08/13            user view           1
22/08/13            blog view           1
```

Now, you can put it in Pentaho Report Designer and group by (inside Report Designer) by  Interaction_date.